# Determining Wayland or X.org on Kinetic Kudu

Tags: xorg, wayland

I used inxi -G to determine whether my system uses Wayland or not this what it shows:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] driver: nvidia v: 515.65.01
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.3 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 43.0 driver: X: loaded: modesetting,nouveau
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.1
```

But as you see the server shows to be X.Org with: Xwayland, so is the system not fully using Wayland, do I need to change something with my graphic setup?

Comment: Xwayland is a compatibility layer working on top of Wayland, so that apps that still use xorg can be displayed on computers using Wayland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your output, you are running an X server on top of Wayland, which is normal. Your applications will likely be a mix of X applications and Wayland applications. In the case of inxi which doesn't yet have full Wayland support it needs to work as an X application, which is fine.

To answer your real question, how to "determine whether my system uses Wayland or not" there are really two things. Look at the boot logs or session startup logs to see what servers are being started (normally depending which session type you choose during login) and secondly, once you have wayland started, check if your applications are actually using it.

A simple trick to check if you have a wayland or x-window is to start the program xeyes. When you are in an x-window then the eyes will track the mouse. When you move into a wayland window that is not an x-window they will not. Start an application like Gnome Terminal or Terminator which have wayland support and you should not see the eyes moving.

If you are in a proper X-server then you will be tracked all the time. In a Wayland server you will be tracked only if you enter an XWayland compatibility window.

Comment: This does not answer the question: *"do I need to change something with my graphic setup?'* I would consider this more of a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for the comment. I tried to edit it to make it more directly answer the question and be clearer why the xeyes part is a more useful answer. Is that better for you?

Answer (score 0):

@Michael, Thanks.

It turns out only GNOME's native apps use wayland, most other apps use XWayland, such as Chromium and Firefox.

I wonder will they ever use wayland by default?

Comment: things will likely convert very slowly. What's needed is more volunteers learning how to program for wayland and helping convert old applications over. Definitely worth starting on the Wayland documentation - https://wayland-book.com/